# safari fullscreen in iOS 7.1 with minimal-ui meta tag

Tags: ios7, safari, mobile-safari, safari-minimal-ui

I've read on multiple sites (including some stackoverflow questions) that there will be a minimal-ui meta tag for iOS 7.1 Safari. So today i've updated my iPad and it seems to have no effect. Can anyone confirm that this should work?

This is my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

Comment: I tested it right now on my iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1 and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem. It doesn't work on ipad air with iOS 7.1. I don't have iphone to test but I will ask somebody.

Comment: Changing viewport by javascript on fly and adding "minimal-ui" doesn't work. The viewport setting "minimal-ui" has to be there in the HTML page when the page is received from the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This option is for iPhone only (right now).

It removes the additional bars on top and bottom of the viewport introduced with iOS 7.0 when the user scrolls up.

This is especially useful in landscape orientation, where a real fullscreen experience will be back, like it was right before iOS 7.

EDIT:
Source: official release notes for iOS 7.1
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.1/

EDIT 2:
Minimal-UI is no longer supporter in iOS 8 (thanks "achairapart")

Comment: Do you have any official source for this?

Comment: I've added the official release notes for iOS 7.1 to my answer. It reads: ... allows minimizing the top and bottom bars on the iPhone ...

Comment: The `minimal-ui` viewport property is no longer supported in iOS 8.

Comment: That's correct: iOS 8 release notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/

Comment: @LeJared Thanks for the link. Super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is for iPhone only. The UI removal is the same process as in iOS 6, which equally never worked on the iPad either. It's not possible to remove Safari UI on the iPad without the user adding the page to the home screen.