# Gray area visible when switching from portrait to landscape using iOS 7.1 minimal-ui

Tags: ios7, mobile-safari, viewport, ios7.1, safari-minimal-ui

In a web application that I am working on, I tried out iOS 7.1's new `minimal-ui` feature (see [safari fullscreen in iOS 7.1 with minimal-ui meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308768/safari-fullscreen-in-ios-7-1-with-minimal-ui-meta-tag)), but I am seeing an issue where an 84px-high gray area appears at the bottom when I switch from portrait to landscape. Also, `document.body.scrollTop` changes to 64 after switching to landscape.

You can see the issue using [this "Hello World" web app](http://www.creativepulse.gr/en/blog/2014/hello-world-web-app-for-android-and-ios): http://www.creativepulse.gr/media/blog/2014/20140123-hello-world/example.html

When I load the app in Mobile Safari on iOS 7.1 iPhone Retina Simulator, everything is fine in portrait mode. However, switching to landscape, the gray area immediately appears.

What is a good way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please attach screenshots? I think I may be having the same issue but I want to confirm.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdb4msspr3vqcwq/minimal-ui_landscape.png?dl=0) what it looks like? Screenshot from my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vopeq/107).

Comment: @stoutie: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Scrolling to the top after the page has rendered helped me. It somehow causes a rerendering and the grey box disappears, however I can't explain what exactly Safari does internally:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: This only temporarily fixes the issue.  A page is still scrollable past its bottom with `minimal-ui` on.  CSS on `html` or `body` to prevent overflow does nothing too.

Comment: See update on my answer below. I linked a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qemad/1) that shows there is still a problem.

Answer (score 12):

I tried for a while to fix this with no luck. I finally decided to do a test where I:

1. Created a new HTML document with the `minimal-ui` meta tag.
2. Left the body of the document empty (no HTML tags), and no styles.

Tested this and the issue still occurs.

**The only conclusion I could come up with is that this is a bug in IOS 7.1**, so I submitted a bug report to Apple. It was reported as **BUG #: 16335579**.

Note that [Mr. kraftwer1's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22590727/419956) worked for me (it's a hack, but will have to do until Apple fixes this). That is, adding... `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` after `orientationChange` works.

Finally, I just wanted to also mention that submitting additional bug reports on this issue to Apple will raise it's priority in their queue.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out and submitting a bug report. I, too, tried a few things to fix this issue, but my attempts did not fix the problem and led to even worse issues, like events being "off" by what appears to be the same 84 pixels.

Comment: No problem. Hoping the Apple QA team tilts their phone to landscape before releasing a major feature like this in future releases.

Comment: ThanksI also have this problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607561/is-there-a-bug-in-the-new-ios-7-1-minimal-ui-viewport-setting). Is it possible to see your post somewhere to be updated?

Comment: @goldj930, where do you go to submit bug reports for Mobile Safari? I need to submit quite a few! (overflow: auto, -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch, minimal-ui landscape, etc). It's been a nightmare trying to appease the Mobile Safari Gods. I'm bout ready to sacrifice a baby.

Comment: Well I have this problem with iOS 8.4 too

Answer (score 2):

The issue does indeed seem to be a bug in iOS 7.0 and 7.1 so far. I've only been able to reproduce it when using the device in landscape.

It happens in three situations that I know of, and in all cases the `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` hack resolves it.

1. When rotating the device into landscape. Can be resolved with:

   ```
   $(window).on('orientationchange', function () {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   });
   ```
2. When dragging from the bottom of the document. Resolved by handling the `scroll` event:

   ```
   $(window).on('scroll', function () {
     var focusedElement;

     if ($(document).scrollTop() !== 0) {
       focusedElement = $(':focus');
       if (!(focusedElement.is('input') || focusedElement.is('textarea'))) window.scrollTo(0, 0);
     }
   });
   ```

   The exceptions for the focused elements are necessary because when the screen keyboard opens, it will also trigger a scroll event in the window.
3. When closing the keyboard—then, all elements lose focus:

   ```
   formLayer.on('blur', 'input, textarea', function () {
     if (!$(':focus').length) window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   });
   ```

Since this issue is only relevant to iOS versions 7.0 and 7.1, it is better to limit this hack to the following expression:

```
var buggyIOS = /\b(?:iPhone|iPod|iPad).*?\bOS 7_[01]/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Refining on the `window.scrollTo(0,0)` solution, I encapsulate in a self describing immediately invoked function expression and execute on document ready and window resize:

```
(function minimalUiFix() {
  var fix = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  };

  $(fix);
  $(window).on('resize.minimal-ui-fix', fix);
})();
```

The benefit is that all the code related to the work around encapsulated together and the reason for the work around is described in the function name. This protects the rest of my beautiful code from being contaminated (too much) by strange work arounds.

There's a lot going on, but I'm using it in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vopeq/107).

This trick doesn't seem to do the trick for me. Check out this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qemad/1). What I have here is pretty simple: a fixed position container with overflow hidden that should take up the whole screen. Scrolling should not be possible, however, I'm still getting some unintended scrollable space. All this trick does is scroll back to the top. It doesn't eliminate the mysterious extra space that is causing the real problem.

But, applying the fix on scroll in addition to ready and resize seems to the be closest to decent work around I could find.

```
(function minimalUiFix() {

  var fix = function () { window.scrollTo(0,0); };
  $(fix);
  $(window).on('resize.minimal-ui-fix', fix);
  $(window).on('scroll.minimal-ui-fix', fix);

})();
```

I think this is the best we can hope for until Apple fixes Mobile Safari or another work around is discovered.

Answer (score 1):

The best fix I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24904557/904102) by Alexander Koleda.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (document.activeElement === document.body && window.scrollY > 0) {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    }
}, true);
```

This also fixes the grey bar when you scroll to the bottom.

Comment: This is completely buggy, scrolls on top everytime a user try to scroll with his finger.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Just remove the Minimal-UI, that got rid of it for me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score -1):

I was reading this post trying to avoid the same issue and found another way to do so.

First let's detect if the device rotated (also we could detect later if is portrait or landscape), to do so I'm going to set up a var for checking mediaqueries from JS:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
```

Then we can listen if there is any change and rewrite the viewport:

```
    mql.addListener(function(m) {
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr("content","width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.2"); // No matter if is landscape or portrait
    });
```

Or we could be more specific and trigger something different for landscape/ portrait

```
    mql.addListener(function(m) {
        if(m.matches) {
            $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr("content","width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.2"); // Portrait
        }
        else {
            $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr("content","width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0"); // Landscape
        }
    });
```

I hope this could help you!

Comment: I didn't think it'd be possible to change meta tags after onload?

Comment: Just give it a try... this is what I use in my projects and works pretty well

Comment: The best code is the code without any explanation. God knows why you mess with maximum-scale.