# Is there a bug in the new iOS 7.1 minimal-ui viewport setting?

Tags: ios, css, html, mobile-safari, viewport

The new "minimal ui" setting in iOS 7.1 is great for landscape websites. My web app uses a fullscreen, absolute positioned div for its content, to give it an app-like feeling. But Safari seems to add just the height of the URL bar at the bottom. I have tried this on different iPhones, same result...

Here is how it looks after the pages loaded:
[image: space at bottom after load]

Is this a bug or something I am doing wrong or missing?

[Click for example (view on iPhone with iOS >= 7.1)](http://lawyered.eu/test/)

Comment: Note that this issue repros for me when loading the page in portrait mode then rotating to landscape.

Comment: Seems to be [a duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391157/gray-area-visible-when-switching-from-portrait-to-landscape-using-ios-7-1-minima)

Comment: @cambecc Thanks for leting be know!

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem with iPhone5+ios7.1+minimal-ui. This code successfully fixes this trouble.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    // Do not scroll when keyboard is visible 
    if (document.activeElement === document.body && window.scrollY > 0) {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Worked for me! This was enough and doing the same on 'orientationchange' isn't necessary.

Answer (score -1):

check out this post: [Gray area visible when switching from portrait to landscape using iOS 7.1 minimal-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391157/gray-area-visible-when-switching-from-portrait-to-landscape-using-ios-7-1-minima)

this fixed it for me:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

setting every time a resize event occurs.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
})
```