# when minimal-ui is set in iOS Safari 7.1 I can scroll past the end of the page

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have a page using the "minimal-ui" setting to hide chrome in Safari on iOS 7.1.

In landscape orientation, you can scroll past the bottom of the page. There are about 165 pixels of grey at the end of the page. It does not snap back like elastic scroll.

Is there a workaround to stop the user scrolling past the bottom of the page?

Notes:

- I only tested in the emulator
- This looks like the same bug as [Is there a bug in the new iOS 7.1 minimal-ui viewport setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607561/is-there-a-bug-in-the-new-ios-7-1-minimal-ui-viewport-setting/24221506#24221506) but they want a solution for when an orientation change causes this, rather than the user manually scrolling.

To reproduce, open any minimal-ui page in mobile Safari (7.1) and scroll past the bottom. This page will do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui">
    </head>
    <body>
    Scroll down and you will find 165 pixels of grey below the white page.
    </body>
</html>
```